# SQL case when in join

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have a query with 2 tables that I want to join, but do to a software bug I can't always join them the same way. The TICKC table is supposed to have a foreignkey populated which would allow a join to the LABLOG table, however it's not always populated, and when it isn't populated I need to join it a different way. So I want to know how to write the join so that it joins on the foreign key if it's present, and if it isn't present then it should join on a different condition. This backup condition always exists, but the primary doesn't always exist.

`LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKC
ON tickc.DELFLAG=0 and TICKC.LABLOGNO = LABLOG.CPK_LABLOG *This is the ideal join, but if TICKC.LABLOGNO is blank then it should join like this instead:*
tickc.NEXTCODE = LABLOG.SCRIPTEXT AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TICKC.CREATEDON, 20) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LABLOG.CREATEDON, 20)`

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Consider a UNION all query with the first being the "ideal" query filtering on non-blank values and the second part with the blank criteria join.

Comment: I don't really know how to write a UNION though. Also would that prevent duplicates? Because the second backup condition always exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKC
    ON (
        tickc.DELFLAG = 0 
        AND TICKC.LABLOGNO = LABLOG.CPK_LABLOG 
    )
    OR (
        TICKC.LABLOGNO IS NULL 
        AND tickc.NEXTCODE = LABLOG.SCRIPTEXT 
        AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TICKC.CREATEDON, 20) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LABLOG.CREATEDON, 20)
    )
```